# how can I disable php file upload in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, upload

I am trying to make upload avatar image for wordpress users in front end. I am using this code

```
$files = $_FILES['post_files'];

foreach($files as $file){

  if(is_array($file)){

    $uploaded_file_type = $file['type'];
    $allowed_file_types = array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
    if(!in_array($uploaded_file_type, $allowed_file_types)) {
      $errors['image_empty'] = __( 'this image is not valid', 'themename' );
    } 

  }

}
```

it's not allowing to upload php file , but if they change the php file extension as png or jpeg they can upload the php file to my server. I try to use `getimagesize()` but I couldn't, I am newbie for php. Or is there any other solution?

thanks for answers

Comment: Why do you need to check this? If they upload a PHP file as an image, the worst that will happen is the image won't show - your server won't run the PHP in it (unless it is really badly configured :)).

Comment: I am using dreamhost and if I can upload the shell.php I can reach all the files and can edit

Comment: Not if it doesn't have a .php extension...

Answer (score 1):

If you use Wordpress image uplaoder(media uploader vs.) use this:

**For disable any file format:**

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','remove_mime_types');
function remove_mime_types($mimes){
  unset( $mimes['mp4'] );
}
```

**For enable any file format:**

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','add_custom_mime_types');
function add_custom_mime_types($mimes){
   return array_merge($mimes,array (
     'ac3' => 'audio/ac3',
     'mpa' => 'audio/MPA',
     'flv' => 'video/x-flv',
     'svg' => 'image/svg+xml'
   ));
}
```

for more information visit paulund's article: https://paulund.co.uk/change-wordpress-upload-mime-types